# Help needed in proving a question in Sequences of real numbers (Convergent , bounded sequences)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I need help in solving it .

Question:(a)  Show that for any positive rational number r , the sequence ${\frac{log n} {n^r} : n\geq 1 }$ is bounded .

(b) Define a sequence by $x_1$=a and $x_2$=b  and $x_n$=  $\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+ x_{n-2})$ for n>2 . Show that ${x_n}$ is a convergent sequence .

Attempt : For (a) kindly verify whether this argument is correct or not . As sequence is a function so I used  L Hopital Rule as infinity is only point where the sequence can tend to infinity and using l hopital rule it tends to 0 . So, I deduced that it must be bounded . Is this approach right ?

For (b) I thought of using the fact that every bounded sequence which is monotone is convergent . But I am not able to prove any of these as sequence is recursive  and I am unable to manipulate it. So , Kindly tell tell how should it i do part (b).

Thanks !!

Comment: Is it $x_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})$ or $x_n = \frac{1}{2(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})}$ ?

Comment: L'Hopital seems a bit of overkill: if you know $e^x>x$ for $x>0$  then you'll get $\frac{1}{r}$ as an upper  bound of the sequence.

Comment: Hint for (b): prove the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I have edited it. Kindly have a look. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Can you post an answer if you have some spare time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I have answered your plea and this is how I would do it. It is like @TheSilverDoe 's solution (a). His is better as it gives the limit. But my motto is "when in doubt, prove it's Cauchy".]

(a) For positive $x$, $e^x>1+x>x$. With $x=r\log n$ this gives $n^r>r \log n$, or $\frac{\log n}{n^r}<1$.

(b) For convenience put $d:=|b-a|$.

Re-writing the recurrence relation we have
$$
x_{m+2}-x_{m+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{m}-x_{m+1})
$$
so that
$$
|x_{m+2}-x_{m+1}|=\frac{1}{2}|x_{m+1}-x_{m}|.
$$

An easy induction now yields that
$$
|x_{r+1}-x_{r}|\leqslant \frac{d}{2^{r-1}}.
$$

Now for any $m,k$ we have
$$\begin{align}
|x_{m+k+1}-x_{m+1}| &=& \left|\sum_{r=1}^{k} (x_{m+r+1}-x_{m+r})\right|\\
&\leqslant & \sum_{r=1}^{k} |x_{m+r+1}-x_{m+r}|\\
&\leqslant & \sum_{r=1}^{k} \frac{d}{2^{m+r-1}}\\
&< & \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{2^{m+r-1}}\\
&=& \frac{d}{2^{m-1}}.
\end{align}
$$

The sequence $(x_n)$ is now easily seen to be Cauchy and so convergent.

Comment: Is my method wrong for (a)?

Comment: This induction is not valid for $x_2 =b , x_1=a$!! as b-a> (b-a)/8

Comment: and in cauchy criterian we don't have eqaulity it's strict inequality

Comment: Tim, my solution was done in too much haste, but I've corrected the initial inequality and it's OK. I've also  made it strict as you prefer - but we can choose to have the Cauchy Crit with weak inequality if we prefer, it makes no difference [Exercise: prove that].

Comment: Tim: your method for (a) is incomprehensible unless you state precisely which version of L'Hospital you are using and check out that the conditions of the theorem are satisfied. You say a sequence is a function: true, but it's a function of a natural number, but to use L'H you need a function of a real variable, you need to  make that clear. As it stands I would give it 4/10 max, because I think it could be repaired with a bit of work.

Comment: you are right , I will do (a) by your method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** I give you four different methods to solve the question *b)* : you can choose the one you prefer.

**First method** : Prove that the sequence $(v_n)$ defined by $v_n = u_{n+1} - u_n$ is a geometric sequence. Deduce its general term, and then deduce the general term of $(u_n)$.

**Second method** : Prove that the sequence $(w_n)$ defined by $w_n = u_n + \frac{u_{n-1}}{2}$ is constant. Deduce that $(u_n)$ is arithmetico-geometric and find its general term.

**Third method :** Prove that the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ defined by $a_n= u_{2n}$ and $b_n =u_{2n+1}$ are adjacent. Then, calculate the limit of $(a_n)$, noticing that $a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{1}{4}(a_n - a_{n-1})$ and applying the same method as the first one.

**Fourth method** : Solve directly the recurrence to find an explicit general formula of $u_n$.